# Typescript - array items from a list of various interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```js
interface NamedAnimal {
  name: string;
}

interface Fish extends NamedAnimal {
  type: 'fish';
  water: 'fresh' | 'salt';
}

interface Dog extends NamedAnimal {
  type: 'dog';
  breed: 'terrier' | 'mutt';
}

type Animal = Fish | Dog;

const animals: Animal[] = [
  { type: 'dog', name: 'rover', breed:'terrier' }
];


function doSomething(animal: Animal) {
  if (animal.breed) {
    // do something doglike.....
  }
}

doSomething(animals[0]);
```

In the above example why does referencing 'animal.breed' give me an error saying 'Property "breed" does not exist on type Fish'

How can I change this so that it can be any of the types listed?

(this is not my actual code but an example of an issue I have).

Comment: In this particular example would it not be more appropriate to check the property that both have (`type`) and then access the `breed` property only in the case that the `type` is `"dog"`?

Comment: I would prefer not to use the type as there are a lot of types an any of them can have the property. Let's say half. But in this example, I think you're right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator to narrow the type down to `Dog`, see the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator).

```
function doSomething(animal: Animal) {
  if ('breed' in animal) {
    // do something doglike.....
  }
}
```

Since both `Fish` and `Dog` have a `type` field you can also use this field to discriminate the type:

```
function doSomething(animal: Animal) {
  if (animal.type === 'dog') {
    // TypeScript now know this is the 'Dog' type
    console.log(animal.breed)
  }
}
```

Comment: Gone with 'breed' in animal approach as I have so many types and some type can have the same property.

Answer (score 0):

[Type assertation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) will help you.
You can specify what type you want to use in a particular case.

```
function doSomething( animal: Animal ) {
   if((animal as Dog).breed) {
      // do something doglike.....
   }
}
```

Comment: Better to use the `in` operator so you do not have to type cast anything.